# 2 resources to notify the same service

Tags: puppet

Wanted to know if it's possible to notify the same service from two different resources:

let's say I have two configuration files:

```
file { "${conf_dir}/1.conf" :
  content => template('1.conf.erb'),
  owner   => $owner,
  group   => $group,
  mode    => '0777',
}

~>file { "${conf_dir}/2.conf" :
  content => template('2.conf.erb'),
  owner   => $owner,
  group   => $group,
  mode    => '0777',
}

~> service { 'some_service' :
  enable     => true,
}
```

I'm not sure if the code above will even execute (because of the '~>' between the file resources)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [notify](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/metaparameter.html#notify) option to notify your service.

With your example :

```
file { "${conf_dir}/1.conf" :
  content => template('1.conf.erb'),
  owner   => $owner,
  group   => $group,
  mode    => '0777',
  notify  => Service['some_service'],
}

file { "${conf_dir}/2.conf" :
  content => template('2.conf.erb'),
  owner   => $owner,
  group   => $group,
  mode    => '0777',
  notify  => Service['some_service'],
}

service { 'some_service' :
  enable     => true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
File {
  owner  => $owner,
  group  => $group,
  mode   => '0777',
  notify => Service['some_service'],
}

file {
  "${conf_dir}/1.conf":
  content => template("${module_name}/1.conf.erb");

  "${conf_dir}/2.conf":
  content => template("${module_name}/2.conf.erb"),
}

service { 'some_service':
  enable => true,
}
```